# Access to a source code a maven dependency

Tags: maven, netbeans

In Netbeans IDE we have an option for maven dependencies called "Download Sources".

After download we can see a package icon in right bottom of that dependency means it is downloaded

But still I cannot see any .java file?

Does the "Download sources" mean something other than .java files?

I tried to see source code of a JSON parser in java .If you know somewhere easy I wonder if you tell me in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans downloads the jar file with the sources from Maven central. It doesn't store individual Java files directly.

To view the downloaded source, you can expand the library node, navigate to the class you are interested in, then double click on it (or right click, then choose "Open").

Another way to jump to the source code is, to use "Goto Source" inside the editor where you use the classes.